# Why can't I properly set up a docker swarm when my docker is set up to use Linux containers?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-container, docker-for-windows

I've been trying to set up a docker swarm for two laptops with Windows 10 and which are in the same network. I've opened the necessary ports and have even tried disabling the firewall for both. However, everytime I try to connect to the manager (I tried them both as the manager), I get either a timeout error or a connection is unavailable error.

I tried reinstalling Docker on both machines and while doing so, noticed the checkbox 'Use Windows Containers'. I checked on that and after completing the installation, was able to set up the swarm properly.

I tried changing it back to use Linux containers but encountered the same problems again.

Can anyone explain why this is so? I assumed that using either Windows or Linux containers wouldn't really matter when setting up a swarm. I want to understand so I can check if I can still create a swarm with Linux containers.

Comment: In your docker's configuration, make sure docker daemon is listening on a TCP port.

Comment: @Cyclops how do I do this? Can you show me how?

Comment: This documentation will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon